# Should i add more columns to my database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Friends i am building a shopping site project in asp.net.

i have used these table for my database

**LoginInfo**

```
Column Name      Data Type      Constraint
UserName         Varchar(100)   Primary key
Password         Varchar(100)   
RoleName         Varchar(100)   
EmailID          Varchar(100)   Unique key
SecurityQuestion Varchar(1000)  
SecurityAnswer   Varchar(100)   
LastLogin        Datetime
```

---

**ProductCategory**

```
Column Name   Data Type     Constraint
CategoryID    Varchar(20)   Primary key
CategoryNam   Varchar(100)  Unique key
Description   Varchar(1000)
```

---

**ProductSubCategory**

```
Column Name      Data Type      Constraint
SubCategoryID    Int            Auto increment , Primary key
SubCategoryName  Varchar(100)   
Description      Varchar(1000)  
CategoryID       Varchar(20)    Foreign key with Product Category
```

---

**ProductSubCategory2**

```
Column Name       Data Type    Constraint
SubCategory2ID     Int         Auto increment , Primary key
SubCategory2Name   Varchar(100) 
Description        Varchar(1000)    
SubCategoryID      Varchar(20)  Foreign key with Product SubCategory
```

---

**CompanyInfo**

```
Column Name Data Type   Constraint
CompanyID   Varchar(20) Primary key
CompanyName Varchar(100)    Unique key
Description Varchar(1000)
```

---

**ProductInfo**

```
Column Name   Data Type Constraint
ProductID     Int           Primary key , auto increment
ProductName   Varchar(100)  
SubCategoryID Int           Foreign key with ProductSubCategory
CompanyID     Varchar(20)   Foreign key with CompanyInfo
Price         Float 
Quantity      Int   
Description   Varchar(1000)
```

---

**ProductStock**

```
Column Name Data Type   Constraint
StockID Int Primary key,auto increment
ProductID   Int Foreign key with ProductInfo
Quantity    Int 
StockType   Enum(‘IN’,’OUT’)    
StockDate   Datetime
```

---

**ProductPhoto**

```
Column Name Data Type   Constraint
PhotoID     Int       Primary key,auto increment
PhotoName   Varchar(100)    
ExtName     Varchar(100)    
PhotoType   Varchar(100)    
PhotoSize   Int 
ProductID   Int          Foreign key with product info
```

So now my Question is in every shopping site there exist 4-5 photos for every product.
So i should add the in database or the will be managed at client side.
Currently i have added only single photo for every product.

Comment: you are storing the username and password as a varchar in your database AND the email address? NICE!  Let me know the site so that I may never use it.

Comment: You don't know that's not a hash of the password

Comment: Where would you hedge your bet?

Comment: Did you ever give a chance to a NoSql solution?

Comment: than sir how to encript these fields

Comment: I think thats another question

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a table linking Photos to ProductID then there is no limit on numbers per product

Comment: sir i have linked that. please read the above code

Answer (score 2):

You should have a photo table that is a child table to the product (parent) with a PK and FK relationship.

Comment: sir i have linked that. please read the above code .Is there any mistake in that

Comment: yes, that will work and is the same solution that Egg Vans also described.

Answer (score 1):

Few findings

1. Why you have RoleName as a column? Why not creating a new table Role (add all types of role) and put a foreign key.
2. Security Question and Security Answer has to be encrypted
3. Why don't you have Created and Modified column?
   How will you track what changes were made to the data and when?
   This has to be tracked as its very important for Shopping cart
4. I didn't find what user will buy what products table?

Comment: sir after these i have cart table, cart infi, order info, drdeails table for user to buy products

Comment: modified column is for any update done by user.